# Getting all possible odd numbers in the user input

Tags: java

I am having difficulties with finding all possible odd numbers for my program. I am required to use a while loop to find all the odd numbers but i am not sure how to print it out. I dont know if im doing anything wrong in this block `while((num1+num2)%2==0)` because that was just a guess. Outline of the program is to get the user to enter 2 numbers that is an even multiple of the other number. I am not sure how that part either. After finding 2 numbers that is an even multiple of the other number, i am supposed to display all the odd numbers between the two numbers. Thanks alot in advance.

```
    import java.util.Scanner; //imports the java utillity scanner

public class MyPrompter{
  public static void main(String[] args){

  System.out.println("Odd number display");


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //scans for user input and stores in "input"

    int num1,num2; //declares the variables i need for the pgrm

 try{    //try statement to check for user input errors
    System.out.println("Please enter your first number: ");
    num1 = input.nextInt(); //stores input for the first number

    System.out.println("Please enter your second number: ");
    num2 = input.nextInt(); //stores input for the second number 

    while((num1+num2)%2==0){ //while loop to find all the odd numbers between the 2 numbers
    System.out.println();
   }
 }
 catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e){ //if the above error is met, message will be sent to the user
               System.out.println("Please enter a valid ROUNDED NUMBER!");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: That code you guessed about is actually complete nonsense (the code you wrote, I mean). Guessing often doesn't work. What do you know about loops?

Comment: not much sir, we just started with while. i only had like a couple simple asgnments with if statements and thats about it. I am really confused as to how to get 2 numbers that is an even multiple of the other and then display all the odd #s.

Comment: Perhaps you should start with something simpler, like a program to print a number, or to find a number that is a multiple of another number. A few points: The variables that are part of the condition of the loop (num1 and num2) must *change* in the body of the loop, otherwise the loop can never end. `System.out.println()` just prints a blank line, not a number.

Comment: As currently written, your program will either print the error message about entering a valid number, an infinite number of blank lines, or nothing.

Comment: i understand like the most basic thing about java and i left alot of things blank in my prgm, because i was confused as to how i would use them in the prgm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
    int num1 = 10;
    int num2 = 50;
    int current =  num1;
    while (current < num2) {
        if (current % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.println(current);
        }
        current++;
    }
```

Set current to equal num1, continue the loop while current is less than num2. For each iteration check if current is odd and output it if it is. Increment current by one.

Comment: 1= 0 is that suppose to mean !=0?